# How to make g++ force me to adhere to C++ standard

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, g++, standards

I am trying to learn C++ having no previous experience with it or C, and I see that some training materials are sometimes trying to teach me C coding instead of C++.

As I don't have enough knowledge to discern if the books are trying to teach me proper C++ or not, I thought I could set some parameter on g++ compiler to save me this problem. 
So here my question is:

How can I set the g++ compiler in Windows so that he won't compile if what I am writing is not pure C++ standard?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: There is no way to do this, C and C++ share some similar syntax, and there is absolutely nothing a compiler is going to do if you use for example `printf()` rather than `cout/cerr` etc. This something you *just have to learn*. There is nothing inherrently bad in learning some of the C library functions (as they can be used from your C++ programs too, you just have learn to make the correct judgement call as to when to use or not..)

Comment: FWIW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the g++ compiler in Windows so that he won't compile if what I am writing is not pure C++ standard?

You cannot. I agree with most of what @Lightness said in his answer. It is not the compiler's job to warn you of all the ways you *might* be invoking undefined behaviour (some of which aren't even detectable at compile time).

*However*, I do not agree with the part of his answer where he equates `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with "warnings turned up way up high".

Quoting from the GCC manuals (v5.2) on what the options actually mean, emphasis mine:

> `-Wall`
>
> This enables **all the warnings** about constructions that some users consider questionable, and **that are easy to avoid** [...]
>
> `-Wextra`
>
> This enables **some extra warning flags** that are not enabled by -Wall.
>
> `-pedantic`
>
> Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++ [...]

Not all constructs that are "not pure C++" actually demand a warning by the standard. There are many things that even `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` will not protect you from, and many things that are quite likely programming errors but not covered by the standard (e.g. `-Wsign-conversion`, `-Wswitch-default`, `-Wlogical-op`, `-Woverloaded-virtual`...)

So the recommendation here is, pick up the compiler manual, and check all the available warning options, selecting the strictest set you can live with. Repeat that process regularly.

Comment: I accepted for giving a background about what permissive means. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No compiler is perfect (most do not 100% implement any particular C++ standard to the letter of the law), but you can turn your warnings way up high then make them errors:

```
g++ source.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror
```

That'll cause most non-standard behaviours to be outright rejected; however, it will also turn some cautionary tales into errors which may or may not be what you want.

Use your best judgement to decide whether you want to use `-Werror`. Personally, I'd recommend it, unless you are forced not to by the requirement to include badly-written third-party library headers.

Still, you can always exclude specific warnings if they get in your way; e.g. by appending `-Wno-unused-variable`.

Consult your toolchain's documentation for available warning switches.

What this *won't* do is detect C idioms in standard-compliant C++ code. That's just not possible.
For that, you have better books, code review sessions and your conscience. :)

Comment: I would also mention adding `-std` flags for the particular standard they want to conform to in order to disable GNU extensions.

Comment: Out of interest, what happens with `-pedantic` if you add a flag like `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @Theolodus: Nothing "happens" with it

Comment: @sjdowling: `-pedantic` disables GNU extensions. I omitted the standard selection flag just as I omitted include paths, library paths, preprocessor definitions... :P